Xcode won't create dSYM files for FirebaseAnalytics
I’m getting dSYM warnings for FirebaseAnalytics when validating my app in Xcode:

Upload Symbols Failed 
The archive did not include a dSYM for the FirebaseAnalytics.framework with the UUIDs > [D080D817-CA37-3B97-8A51-421A372C12DB]. Ensure that the archive's dSYM folder includes > a DWARF file for FirebaseAnalytics.framework with the expected UUIDs.  

I've looked at the package contents of my app archive and there are no dSYM files related to Firebase in the dSYMs folder. I do have one for my app though.
Current situation:

I’m using Firebase v10.29.0 (installed via Swift Package Manager)
Analytics is enabled for my app in the Firebase Console
Events and Crashlytics log messages are being logged are visible in
the Firebase Console
My local GoogleService-Info.plist has IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED set to ‘No’ (but I’ve tried changing it to ‘Yes’ which doesn’t fix the problem)
I’ve ensured "Debug Information Format" is set to "DWARF with dSYM File" for both Debug and Release configurations
The Run Script build phase is running this: "${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run"
I have all the correct Input Files paths in the script
I’ve cleaned the project and rebuilt multiple times

I’m out of ideas. What else can I try?
Thanks

Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/71139977/1271826.

I've got a dozen packages in my app, and since shifting to SPM (from Cocoapods), I have only three frameworks generating this error, and they are all Firebase/Google (FirebaseAnalytics, GoogleAppMeasurement, and GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport). None of my other packages generate this error. I wonder if there is some issue in how they generated their binaryTargets? Maybe this is a question we have to direct to them?

FWIW, I’ve submitted a request there and I will let you know if I hear anything.

@Rob I'm facing the same issue, did you get any response yet ?

No response, but it looks like they're working on it.

This solution works correctly to avoid these warnings in general, my error was hermes.framework and it worked correctly https://stackoverflow.com/a/70625475/24289057

@JuanGiron - that link is to a post about ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption which doesn't have anything to do with this problem with dSYMs.

Might be a Xcode 16 issue caused by a change in how they process dSYMs. Discussion here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/13543, including possible workarounds.
I was staring at the same issue. Swift app on Xcode 16, with Firebase 10.28, 10.29, etc using SPM. Also, followed textbook steps exactly as you have, all listed here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios.
Was a bit puzzling to diagnose, until I tried uploading of a new build of a different app I had already published, and it popped up the same dSYM problems.

Thanks @sas for the useful information!
It is suggested to dismiss the warning from Google's document.
"When submitting apps built with Xcode 16 to the App Store, you might encounter Upload Symbols Failed warnings related to the Google Mobile Ads and User Messaging Platform SDKs. You can dismiss these warnings because these SDKs are static frameworks, which don't need a separate dSYM file for debugging." - From Google Mobile Ads doc.
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/privacy/data-disclosure

I resolved this issue by upgrading React Native to version 0.76. The latest (0.76) version includes improved support for Hermes and ensures that dSYM files are correctly generated and included in the archive.
You can check and verify from this comment on GitHub
Steps to Upgrade:
Use react-native-upgrade-helper to assist with upgrading your project dependencies and configuration files:
Uninstall, Clean and Rebuild the Project
Ensure Hermes is enabled in your project:
Why Upgrading Works
React Native 0.76 introduced updates that better handle Hermes integration, including generating and including dSYM files in the archive. This resolves the missing symbol issue that often occurs in older versions.
